# How can I turn off the information in the viewfinder on my Nikon D800?

Tags: camera-settings, viewfinder

It's really annoying and disrupting when I am shooting a galaxy on dark nights =_=. I couldn't find any option in the menu.

[image: inline]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn off this information from being displayed in the d800's viewfinder. I don't think any Nikon offers this choice.